# App freezes when tapping on a NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink

When I tap on a **NavgationLink** to move to the next screen, my view **freezes** and the **CPU usage** goes to **99%**.

I recently updated my Xcode (version 15.0), and started working on a new project. Now the issue is I have **4-5 NavigationLinks** in a single View and when I try to move to the next View my app freezes there and I have to restart the app to get it functional again but getting the same issue at the respective screen.

Here is my code:

```swift
struct SettingsView: View {

    var body: some View {

     VStack {
        Group {
                    
           NavigationLink {
                EditProfileView()
                    .hideNavigationBar
           } label: {
                SettingsRow(row: .editProfile)
           }
                    
           Divider()
                    
           NavigationLink {
                AccountVerificationView()
                    .hideNavigationBar
           } label: {
                SettingsRow(row: .accountVerification)
           }
                    
           Divider()
                    
           NavigationLink {
                ChangePhoneNoView()
                    .hideNavigationBar
           } label: {
                SettingsRow(row: .changeNumber)
           }
                    
           Divider()
        }
                 
     Group {
           SettingsRow(row: .notification, isToggleOn: $notificationOn)
                    
           Divider()
                    
           SettingsRow(row: .conversation, isToggleOn: $openToConversation)
                    
           Divider()
                    
           NavigationLink {
                MatchedFriends()
                   .hideNavigationBar
           } label: {
                SettingsRow(row: .matchedFriends)
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

And this is my main View:

```swift
@main
struct KoyApp: App {
    
    // register app delegate for Firebase setup
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                SettingsView()
                    .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                        Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct HideNavBar : ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

extension View {
 
   var hideNavigationBar: some View {
        modifier(HideNavBar())
    }
}
```

Is this a new bug in Xcode or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For `NavigationLink` to work, you need to wrap them (SettingsView) in a `NavigationStack`.
What is `.hideNavigationBar`?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine  I am using custom navigation bar. So, to hide the navigation Bar for next view, I have created `.hideNavigationBar` modifier. And I have already added **NavigationStack** in my main View. I had update my code.

Comment: `...when I try to move to the next View my app freezes there`, which next view?
 Does the freeze happens if you comment the `.hideNavigationBar` for that view?
 
 Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The View I gave in the NavigationLink's destination, it does not move to that screen but else it freezes. and for your next question, I commented `.hideNavigationBar` but getting the same issue

Comment: what if you replace the existing destination with, for example 
 `NavigationLink(destination: Text("nextview"))`. Since I cannot run your code I can only guess that it maybe due to the destination view.

Comment: I had changed my destination with `Text("new view")`, and the app does not freezes means I have some issue in my destinations. I had tried one more thing, I changed **NavigationStack** with **NavigationView** and this solves my problem too but the concern is the NavigationView in now deprecated

Comment: Switching to NavigationView isn’t a solution just a workaround, you likely have an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: how about showing us the code for one of the destination view that does not work.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thanks for the help, I was debugging from that time and came to know that there is some issue with my `AccountVerificationView` destination.